# plot multiple datasets with gnuplot script from stdin

Tags: gnuplot, stdin

I am trying to plot some data with gnuplot. I want to use a static script.gp file and feed it from stdin with my data. I also have multiple datasets that I need to pass to the script.

script.gp:

```
set term jpeg
set encoding utf8
plot '<cat' index 0 with lines, plot '' index 1 with lines
```

data:

```
1 2
2 2


0 0
7 4
```

command:

```
cat data | gnuplot script.gp
```

This doesn't work, since I'm guessing it tries to reread from stdin. Is there a way I can do this, or do I have to use temporary files to store my data?

Comment: if your data is already in a file, why don't you just plot the file? If the data is coming from a command, why don't you ask gnuplot to plot the output of the command? e.g. `plot '< for i in {1..50}; do echo "$RANDOM"; done' w l` maybe `help special` can give some hint for your case

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The data is not already in a file, it's generated on the fly (by a php script).  My thought was to have a gnuplot script, version controlled and all, describing the format of the plots I want, and call that script with different datasets in order to generate the plots.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I 've found so far has plenty of drawbacks, however it kind of does the job:
Use 'gnuplot -e' and cat the script file into the command:

```
cat data | gnuplot -e "$(cat script.gp)"
```

change script.gp using `;` at the end of every line, remove all comments and change the plot command using `'-'` instead of `'<cat'` and removing `index`:

```
set term jpeg;
set encoding utf8;
plot '-' with lines, '-' with lines
```

change the data format, seperating each dataset with a line with `e`:

```
1 2
2 2
e
0 0
7 4
```

Comment: This works great! Although I think in your second code block it should be `plot '-' with lines, '-' with lines`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the special file '<' which allows you to call the php script and you can have your gnuplot file `plot.gp`:

```
set term jpeg;
set encoding utf8;
set output file_out

my_cmd1=sprintf('< my_script %s', my_file1)
my_cmd2=sprintf('< my_script %s', my_file2)
plot my_cmd1 with lines, my_cmd2 with lines
```

and you call in a shell with:

```
gnuplot -e 'my_file1="input1.txt"; my_file2="input2.txt"; file_out="my_out.jpg"' plot.gp
```